# Switching regulator (TI LM2678) not working on load > 100mA

Tags: voltage, power, pcb, switch-mode-power-supply

I am a (joung) programmeer and I recently began studying some electronics&AVR programming.

I am trying to use a step down voltage regulator (LM2678-5.0) to transform battery voltage (9/12V) into a suitable 5V. I am not using a simple LM7805 since this is part of a bigger robotic project, where I need to transform more than 1A, and it would be nice to spare energy (=less battery weight).

I built this schematic (photos below); with a 10kOhm load I get 5.02V; but as I attach a load to it, voltage drops. As example, as I attach a 20mA led, I get about 3V. I tried attaching a little (~400mA) motor, but it doesn't start (there's no voltage!).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

[image: rear]
[image: front]
[image: schematic]

P.S.: inductors and capacitors has been chosen accordnigly to Texas Instruments online simulation tool

Comment: What sort of battery are you using? Is its output also sagging under the load?

Comment: Also, what is its current rating for L1?

Comment: No battery yet, tested with a regulated power supply. I set it 10V

Comment: What is the current limit of the DC power supply set to?

Comment: Yes, the inductor is rated 22uH, bought it in an electronic store

Comment: What is the *current rating* of the inductor? Not the inductance, the current rating? If it doesn't have a DC current rating, it's not an appropriate part for this sort of circuit.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by DCPS?

Comment: DCPS= DC Power supply. Regulated labaratory PS has both voltage *and* current limit.

Comment: DCPS has max 10A. Checking the inductor, can't find where I put the datasheet

Comment: Ok, this is the datasheet.
http://www.neosid.de/produktblaetter/neosid_Festinduktivitaet_Sd75.pdf

Can't find dc current rating. Does this mean it couldn't work in this circuit?

Comment: The current rating is the \$I_{max}\$ column in the table of values. That inductor should be good for output currents of a few hundred mA, but it will never deliver 1A.

Comment: Imax is specified as 560mA, and this inductor is marketed as a high-frequency suppressor, not a power inductor. I would not consider this an appropriate choice of inductor for the application. Something like the Vishay IHLP4040 series would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, but could this be the reason of my problem? I have a 2V drop with a small 20mA led.

Comment: As well as the inductor (which is clearly an issue at higher currents), I don't see C2 there at all. A 470nF ceramic cap is suggested on the datasheet and you've got nothing like that wot I can see. You need to bypass the input on a switching regulator **well**.

Comment: This inductor is like a ferrite bead...

Comment: In addition to the comments on the inductor you need capacitors with low ESR.  They look like aluminum electrolytics which in my experience are not good enough for use in switching supplies.  Tantalum or polymer aluminum are usually much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common trap for beginners and DCDC converters !
Your inductor is not up to the job.

These kind of DCDC converters there is always a LARGE INDUCTOR, it needs to be large so it can handle the current. Well actually it needs to be able to store a large amount of magnetic energy. I did not see such an inductor in your photos !

You small inductor can only store a small amount of magnetic energy and then it saturates, it cannot store more energy. As a result the output voltage of your DCDC converter drops.

If you replace the inductor with a more suitable one, you have a better chance it will work.
Here are some pictures of suitable inductor types: [toroid inductor](http://old.magnetica.eu/tag/inductor/) or [SMD power inductors](http://www.directindustry.com/prod/shaanxi-shinhom-enterprise-co-ltd/product-98129-910725.html).

Also study the datasheet, ideally you want an inductor that can handle at least 2x the current you need at the output.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I'll go buying a larger inductor.

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely not an appropriate inductor to use in that circuit.
I'm assuming from the options presented in the datasheet you linked that the one you have is part number 00 6122 04 listed on page 2.
Its DC resistance is almost 1 ohm and its current rating is only 560mA (and we don't even  know if that's average or saturation).
For an inductor used in a DCDC converter, I also usually like to see some data on how it would behave at my DCDC converter's switching frequency, but that datasheet is only giving info for 100kHz while your LM2678 is operating at 260kHz.
You're going to need something significantly bigger and better spec'ed to do the job properly.

You may also want to think about a better diode too as the 1N5819 is only good for an average current of 1A.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know those things about inductors. Learned something new.

Comment: About the diode: I know the 1A problem, but I can't find a through-hole which can handle more current. Can I put it in parallel with other 1N5819?

Comment: @GiacomoFabris: The 1N5822 is the 3A part, but will need a larger hole.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this was just a test board, it's the first time I use switching regulator. Obviously needs also better connectors, and maybe also better soldering ;)

Comment: My first attempts looked very much like that too ;)